# Convert pandas dataframe to LaTeX without printing index

Tags: python, pandas, latex

I'm trying to print a dataframe as a LaTeX table, but I seem to have two bad options. (Note I'm using `io.formats.style.Styler.to_latex` rather than `dataframe.to_latex` since there's a deprecation warning on the former. But `dataframe.to_latex` doesn't solve my issue anyway, it just changes it to a different issue.

By default the LaTeX table looks like this:

```
------------------------
            column name
index name
------------------------
data        data
data        data
```

with the name of the index one row down from the name of the column.

I can do:

```
df[index_as_column] = df.index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

So my table looks like this:

```
------------------------
    index_as_column column name
------------------------
0   data            data
1   data            data
```

The index gets printed whether I like it or not (I don't).

So my question is, how do I get a table with the column names on the same line and no index printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas 1.4.0+ we can use `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.hide` with `axis='index'`:

like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2.2, "dogs"], [3, 4.4, "cats"], [2, 6.6, "cows"]],
                  index=["ix1", "ix2", "ix3"],
                  columns=["Integers", "Floats", "Strings"])
s = df.style.highlight_max(
    props='cellcolor:[HTML]{FFFF00}; color:{red};'
          'textit:--rwrap; textbf:--rwrap;'
    ).hide(axis='index')
print(s.to_latex())
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_latex` has the argument `index` which is `True` by default (see https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html). Set this one to false and you do not get the index in the output.

So

```py
df.to_latex(index=False)
```

Comment: OP is NOT using `to_latex`.